# Retrieve data from Firebase on Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Can someone help me fix it?

Following code works without any error, however, it does not retrieve data from Firebase and show in the TextView.

```
private fun viewData() {
    val postReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("dataID")
    val dbView= findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtFdbData)
    val postListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post::class.java)
            dbView.text=post?.postName
        }
        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        }
    }
    postReference.addValueEventListener(postListener)
    Toast.makeText(this,"Retrieved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Above code is called when I tap the button 'btnView'

```
 viewButton = findViewById(R.id.btnView)
        viewButton.setOnClickListener {
            viewData()
        }
```

When I hit the button it shows the toast message 'Retrieved' and the default value given in the TextView (txtFdbData) is deleted (or may be replaced with an empty string?, I do not know).

Following is the post Class

```
data class Post (
    val postName: String="",
    val postDescription:String="")
```

I am working on Android Studio, using Kotlin and Firebase Realtime Database.

Comment: Your listener is ignoring errors.  Log the exception in onCancelled to see if there was an error.

Comment: Operation to firebase is asynchronous. So your `Toast` shows message before execute the operation. That's mean your `Toast` doesn't reflect the actual result. Add your database structure to investigate more

Comment: It replace by the empty string .So check the data in `post` and in `firebase`.

Comment: @DougStevenson Can you help me do that?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman 
{
"dataID" : {
"-LwM6GI3UwBxMkdoWiVe" : {
"postDescription" : "description1",
"postName" : "Test Data"
}
}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You query to database return list of items. So loop through it and try to get `Post`. Check below:

```
override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    dataSnapshot.children.forEach {childSnapshot ->
        val post = childSnapshot.getValue(Post::class.java)
        dbView.text=post?.postName
    }
}
```

Comment: Bravo, it worked. Can you tell me what was wrong with my code? I am totally a new to this and know nothing. Just started learning.

Comment: getReference("dataID") is not your data node it is your parent node. Then you have to access their children .

Comment: You code is absolutely fine. You just miss one thing that I mentioned in my answer,  In your database `dataID` can contains list of `Post` with key like `-LwM6GI3UwBxMkdoWiVe`. In your code you try to parse that key as `Post` object which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

`getReference("dataID")`  is not your data node it is your parent node.
Then you have to access their children using  `getChildren()` method.

Change you on data change method with this.

```
 override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        val post = postSnapshot .getValue(Post::class.java)
        dbView.text=post?.postName
         }
    }
```